# Do Polish citizens support law that allows judges to be disciplined for criticizing the system?

Tags: law, judiciary, separation-of-powers, public-opinion, poland

Polish President Duda has adopted on October, 2nd 2020 a divisive law that allows judges to be disciplined for criticizing the system. The legislation, which has drawn condemnation from the European Union, bars judges from questioning judicial appointments made by the president and forbids them from engaging in political activity. It has been criticized by the European Union, some judges and some political

But how do Polish feel about it ? I haven't read any article from Polish sources telling if the people where supportive or against it. Furthermore PiS, president Duda party, seems likely to win another election.

Comment: Polish law is not about punishing judges that criticize the system, it is about not allowing creation of judicial caste that will be above will of the people, untouchable and practically irreplaceable. And considering latest elections, this move is mostly popular in Polish electorate.

Comment: This question is very broad- some citizens will be against it and some for it.  Maybe the question should state:  "What does polling about this law state? "What is the likelihood of this law standing or being overturned?

Comment: @rs.29 On of the basics of separation of power is judiciary independence. Judiciary is a professional civil service independent of political whims and fashions. This move by PiS is part of broader campaign designed to turn judiciary into kangaroo court controlled by PiS.

Comment: @Miech Judiciary certainly is not a service. It's one of 3 classical branches of government ( judicial, legislative, executive). All 3 branches derive their legitimacy from the will of the people. Therefore, judiciary most be held responsible for their actions by the people, like other two branches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not totally sure this is answering your question, but since the EU has taken action against Poland on this matter, a [related poll](https://rmx.news/article/article/state-law-more-important-than-eu-law-for-poles-survey) is probably a good proxy indicator.

> Respondents were also asked about the European Commission's conflict over Poland's judicial reform conflict. For that question, 22 percent of respondents viewed the European Commission's actions negatively and 20 percent “rather negatively". Another 30 percent viewed the actions positively and 17 percent rather positively.

As you probably know, the opposition has organized [protests](https://www.dw.com/en/poland-adopts-controversial-judicial-law/a-52283771) in Poland on the matter etc.